# Data storage for IoT devices

Tags: database, iot

How data is stored for Internet of Things devices? Are they stored in traditional relational database format (tables, rows , columns ) or some other format? Is there some software or algorithm applied to raw sensor data to organize them ?
Any reference to research paper is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IoT data will be stored in various different formats depending on a few factors, but not the least including:

1. Format of the server ingested data files

The data could be coming directly from a sensor or being relayed from an internet connected device (think cell phone).  If it's coming directly from a sensor and your utilizing the native SDK provided, then it's likely to be coming over in a hard file format or XML.  If you're pinging it off a cell phone, you may be translating the data locally and then pushing it to the server. Depending on your scenario, the format of data coming to server will be defined and you'll need to weigh the processing costs of further format changes with the rest of the considerations below.

2. Need for view access after ingestion

Depending on how often you access the data, post-ingestion, will determine whether or not you want to stick the values into a NoSQL DB (like SOLR or MongoDB), a relational DB (like SQL) or keep them in file format and store them in Hadoop.  If you're going with Hadoop, I'd suggest Cloudera over other flavors and you'll need to keep in mind the limitation of 100 million files regardless... so don't forget to do your archiving strategy with HAR.

3. Need for computational processing after ingestion

You may require that the data be analyzed post-ingestion, and that process may have its own requirements.  For example, during one Mobile ECG build I needed to analyze the data via WFBD (an MIT Open Source Library) which required the files to be fed in a specific format... so we went with a Hadoop archive and a SQL/SOLR active db.

4. Backend framework language

Hadoop is accepted across the board by all languages, but specific DB methods will require you to consider whether your going with a .NET approach or a JAVA (or others) approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I just wanted to know if k-anonimity can be applied on data collected in IoT.

Comment: Can data compression  be included in any of these steps and where? I am thinking compression can potentially reduce the transmission time and costs if the sensor data is abundant. If anyone is interested in compression for IoT I would like to learn about the challenges they are facing and when data compression is worth considering.